# How to make an iframe not reloading itself in a rails 4 layout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm actually making a rails app for a music band. And they recently asked for a music streamer to play music throughout the whole application.

As they're on [bandcamp](https://bandcamp.com), I thought that I might as well do that via the iframes they provide, before building a javascript streaming feature in some time.

But, here's the issue : when you put an iframe in your `application.html.erb`, it's reloading itself everytime the user is loading a new page. Exactly as if the code wasn't in the layout, but on every pages instead.

So far I've tried some stuff, like putting the iframe in a partial and calling it via : `render 'layouts/shared/music_widget'`, but the issue stay the same.

As I've found nothing on the web so far, I'm guessing I've missed something ( maybe I lack some knowledge in rails' basic magic )... so, I'd be glad if someone here could help me with this one.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

That’s because when you reload, a completely new page is generated and downloaded by your browser. The whole HTML is replaced with every HTTP request. To achieve what you want, you’d have to look into asynchronous solutions and SPA’s (Single-page Applications), basically having only one page and replacing the content of it using AJAX.

I suggest using [batman.js](https://github.com/batmanjs/batman-rails), a great library which makes it relatively easy to switch to AJAX page loading using Rails. A big advantage is that it was built with Rails in mind, and as such it couldn’t be more simple to integrate it with your current application. However it does require you to learn CoffeeScript.

Alternatives include AngularJS, Ember.js, Backbone.js, each of them having gems helping with Rails integration.

I am sure there are many more, but I listed the most popular choices. You could also create your own JavaScript to handle that. The easiest solution in such a case would be to have the big `<div>` containing everything but the iframe; bind to the `click` event of `a` elements with a special attribute set (for example `data-ajax="true"`), make an AJAX request to the URL specified in `href`, and replace the content of the big `<div>` with the response.

---

In any case, you’ll need to read more about [Single-page Applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application).

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a similar project which requires the use of iframe to play music thoughout the website. For that I used two layouts, one is the application.html.erb and another one is called player.html.erb

Now Application .html.erb is the one which contains header, footer and  the iframe. And the other layout does not contain any of these and is the one which is used to   for the actions to be opened in the url.

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding. Can you be more explicit about how you did it please ? Cause I've tried to render the "player" partial into the "application" layout and also did it the other way. But you seem to suggest that you managed to have 2 layout at the same time... and I'm unable to find how you did it.

Comment: I have used 3 layouts in my project.The application layout is used for all actions in which user is not currently signed in.After login I redirect user to home page, which uses logged_in layout and contain iframe. Now I provided the dashboard page url in that iframe. Now when user is logged in he is redirected to home page with dashboard page opened in iframe. Now we have to open all the links inside that iframe and pass the link to src attribute of iframe with jquery. Now the links to be opened in iframe uses player layout which doesnt contain header and footer. Hope it helps.

Comment: So, basically, when your user is logged, all the links a non-logged user normally opens via his browser are now oppened in an iframe ? And the music player, which isn't in the iframe, can keep playing while you're browsing the website.

Comment: Exactly! And the layout for action depend upon whether user is logged in or not. If user is logged in then use player layout else application layout.

Comment: @Eraw You can upvote the answer if you think its useful

Comment: Well, actually, this wasn't useful to me at all, since I don't want my users to run my whole app through an iframe just to have some nice music playing in the background. But in some other cases it should do the trick, I guess.